# Does $A/B \cong C/D$ and $B \cong D$ imply $A \cong C$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

Say that for some group $A$ who has a normal subgroup $B$, and for some group $C$ who has a normal subgroup $D$, we know that $A/B$ is isomorphic to $C/D$ and that $B$ is isomorphic to $D$. Is $A$ necessarily isomorphic to $C$?

EDIT: What if there is a homomorphism $\sigma: A \to C$?

Comment: No, $A = C_2 \times C_2$ and $C= C_4$ are counterexamples.

Comment: Another example would be $A=S_n$, $B=A_n$, C=A_n\times C_2$.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by the_fox, the answer to your question is “no.” In fact, if we have groups $A$ and $C$, normal subgroups $M\triangleleft A$ and $N\triangleleft C$, we can have:

1. $A\cong C$ and $M\cong N$, but $A/M$ not isomorphic to $C/N$.
2. $A\cong C$, $A/M\cong C/N$, but $M$ not isomorphic to $N$.
3. $M\cong N$, $A/M\cong C/N$, but $A$ not isomorphic to $C$.

Here are examples of each, with finite abelian groups. Cyclic groups are written multiplicatively, and when required, generated by an element $x$.

1. $A=C=C_p\times C_{p^2}$, $M=C_p\times\{e\}$, $N=\{e\}\times\{x^p\}$. Then $A/M\cong C_{p^2}$, but $C/N\cong C_p\times C_p$.
2. $A=C_p\times C_{p^2}$, $M=C_p\times \{x^p\}$, $N=\{e\}\times C_{p^2}$. Then $A/M\cong C/N\cong C_p$, but $M\cong C_p\times C_p$ and $N\cong C_{p^2}$.
3. $A=C_p\times C_p$, $C=C_{p^2}$, $M= C_p\times\{e\}$, and $N=\{x^p\}$. Then $M\cong N\cong C_p$, and $A/M\cong C/N\cong C_p$.

Comment: When is it the case that $A/B\cong C/D$ and $B \cong D$ implies that $A\cong C$? Is this known?

Comment: @Anonymous: In this context? Practically never. You would have to impose extremely strong conditions on $A$, $C$, $B$, and $D$, which essentially will amount to you having to front-load your conclusion into the hypotheses.

Comment: If you have a homomorphism $\phi:A\to C$ (onto) and normal subgroup $B$ in $A$ with image $D$ under $\phi$, is $C/D$ a quotient of $A/B$?

Comment: @Anonymous That is well outside this question; $C/D$ would be isomorphic to $A/(B+N)$, where $N$ is the kernel of $\phi$.

Comment: Thank you! +1. Just one last question: is $/(+)\approx(/)/$?  (By $B+N$ do you mean $B \cap N$?

Comment: @Anonymous: No to both. $B+N$ is the smallest subgroup that constains both $B$ and $N$, using additive notation (because we are dealing with abelian groups). It is the **opposite** of $B\cap N$. And “$(A/B)/N$” is nonsense, because $N$ is not a subgroup of $A/B $, it is a subgroup of $A$.

Comment: Okay thank you! +1 again. Where did you find the result that $A/(B+N) \approx C/D$? I wanted to read the proof.

Comment: @Anonymous: It’s an easy corollary of the isomorphism theorems.

Answer (score 0):

This is one everyone knows:

$n\neq m\implies \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\not \cong \Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z, $ but $n\Bbb Z\cong m\Bbb Z.$

But you still see the mistake all the time.